# Multiline controller to grow the height down

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a multiline MFC checkbox created like this

```
checkBox = new CButton(); 
checkBox ->CreateEx(WS_EX_LEFT, _T("BUTTON"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_MULTILINE, m_clRect, pclPanel, controlid))
```

Which result in this

[image]

But I want the text to start from the middle of the checkbox and grow down like this [image]

Anybody knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [`BS_TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I had not. And I thank you for that! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BS_TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which *"Places text at the top of the button rectangle."*